# How to link two android projects in eclipse juno version on Mac platform

Tags: android

I have two android projects one gameproj project written in  C++ and another one is inapp purchase storeproj, which is a library java project,i need use java methods of storeproj in gameproj

for linking store proj to gameproj i followed these steps:

1)In the properties of gameproj in javabuildpath i linked storeproj under projects section
2)In the Libraries section also i added storeproj

I'm getting a link error saying "testclass cannot be resolved to a type"
(testclass is a Javaclass inside storeproj)??
Anysuggestions will be thankfully accepted.

here is my project.properties file

```
 # This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
 # Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
 #
 # This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
 #
 # To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
 # "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
 # project structure.
 #
 # To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
#proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-17
android.library.reference.1=../../cocos2dx/platform/android/java
```

Comment: Could you please paste the project.properties of gameproj?

Comment: When u mean project.properties of gameproj i didn't get it? do u mean the projectpropertiesfile inside proj.android folder of the project

Comment: Yeah, that one.. Inside the folder there should be a project.properties file

Comment: My projects name is balooney zoo ,here is my project.properties file

Comment: I believe that storeproj is inside ../../cocos2dx/platform/android/java. Am I right? If yes, what's inside this path? All of the .java files I think.

Comment: storeproj is a separate project linked to gameproj in addition to this gameproj is making use of cocos2dx framework java proj which is also linked to gameproj , i am calling the java method of store proj from java class of coco2dx framework